# Assign a user role in wordpress plugin Ultimate Member registration form depending on the entered email address

Tags: wordpress, ultimate-member

We use Ultimate Member for a customer section of a business website. Customers can register with their customer number and email address to get access to some downloads. To validate the registration process, I added a custom validation script to the fiels 'number' and a list of valid numbers and email addresses in the backend.
Works fine so far!

How can I now add a rule to automatically assign a user role depending on the email address?
For example, in my backend address list the entry has the flag 'IT-department', the role 'poweruser' is assigned. Otherwise the default rule.

Comment: After 8 months without any response or assistance for my problem, I decided to consult ChatGPT. I successfully tested the provided solution and shared it here, marking it as the correct answer. I also mentioned that the answer was created by AI and approved. However, my response has now been deleted because AI content isn't allowed. Perhaps, if I hadn't mentioned that the answer was from an AI, it would still be online. Strange new world...

Answer (score 0):

I have a problem similar to the one you've already solved. I'd like to send unique numbers to a known population via snail mail and have each user enter their number during registration to validate them. Would you consider sharing your custom validation script?